Why both of the custom decorators are called even if I only called one of them?
This is my custom decorator class. When I decorate them for functions and classes, auxiliary info is printed if these items are used.
# decorator.py
class BaseDecorator(object):
    """
    Base decorator class
    """

    def __init__(self, message, source=''):
        self.message = message
        self.source = source

    def __call__(self, func):
        print(f"{type(func).__name__.capitalize()} `{func.__name__}` {self.message}")
        if self.source:
            print(f"Source: {self.source}")

        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return func(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper

class Important(BaseDecorator):
    """
    The decorated content is of great importance!
    """

    def __init__(self, reason: str = '** No reason given. **'):
        super().__init__("is important: " + reason)


class Copied(BaseDecorator):
    """
    The decorated content is copied from somewhere.
    """

    def __init__(self, source=''):
        super().__init__("is copied.", source)

And when I use them like this:
from decorators_module import Important, Copied  # Assuming these decorators are defined in another module

class Solution:
    @Important(reason="This function does something crucial.")
    def critical_task(self):
        ...

    @Copied(source="Inspired by StackOverflow")
    def helper_function(self):
        ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    solution = Solution()
    solution.critical_task()  # Only this function is called

Both the information in Copied and Important is printed. As I expected, only information in Important should be printed.
These are the actual outputs:
Function `critical_task` is important: This function does something crucial.
Function `helper_function` is copied.
Source: Inspired by StackOverflow

Can anyone help me to figure out the problem? Great appreciation in advance!

Your print() happens during the application of the decorator, so you get output for all decorated functions, whether or not they're ever actually called.  wrapper() is the only part of the decorator that is specific to the decorated function being called.

I think this isnt true. all the print statements are in the call method, and that method is only executed when an instance is called

@jasonharper You are absolutely right!

sorry im probably not right, when i test some thing by putting time.sleep here and there it seems theyre executed on creation

@JasperBart that's not True. decorator is (implicitly) called immediately, at the time of definining the function

Your print staments are in the wrong place. Move then thus:
# decorator.py
class BaseDecorator(object):
    """
    Base decorator class
    """

    def __init__(self, message, source=''):
        self.message = message
        self.source = source

    def __call__(self, func):

        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print(f"{type(func).__name__.capitalize()} `{func.__name__}` {self.message}")
            if self.source:
                print(f"Source: {self.source}")
            return func(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper


Thanks to @jasonharper and @Jasper Bart!
After modifying the __call__ method like this, the output works like a charm! All the preprocess should be put in the wrapper!
    def __call__(self, func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print(f"{type(func).__name__.capitalize()} `{func.__name__}` {self.message}")
            if self.source:
                print(f"Source: {self.source}")
            return func(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper


When your function is created, __call__ is called. then it returns the function named wrapper, whitch is called when the decorated function is called. this means that you have to put that print statements in the wrapper function. your code becomes then something like this:
# decorator.py
class BaseDecorator(object):
    """
    Base decorator class
    """

    def __init__(self, message, source=''):
        self.message = message
        self.source = source

    def __call__(self, func):
        print("some sort of initing message...")

        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print(f"{type(func).__name__.capitalize()} `{func.__name__}` {self.message}")
            if self.source:
                print(f"Source: {self.source}")
            return func(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper

class Important(BaseDecorator):
    """
    The decorated content is of great importance!
    """

    def __init__(self, reason: str = '** No reason given. **'):
        super().__init__("is important: " + reason)


class Copied(BaseDecorator):
    """
    The decorated content is copied from somewhere.
    """

    def __init__(self, source=''):
        super().__init__("is copied.", source)

